# Intersection of the graphs of two functions

Tags: numerical-methods, math-software

Let $$f(x)={x^3-14x^2+7x+203\over(x-3)(8-x)}$$ I want to find the two solutions of $$f(x)f''(x)=(f'(x))^2,\qquad3\le x\le8$$

This is the first time i am using maple, and i cannot get the graph to work out.

Comment: Which functions "intersect"? Which graph are you wanting to work out?

Comment: What are the functions you are trying to find the intersection of?????

Comment: Are you looking at 
$$F(x)=\frac{x^3-14x^2+7x+203}{(x-3)(8-x)}$$
and its derivatives $F'(x)$ and $F''(x)$ and finding the points at which $F(x)$, $F'(x)$, and $F''(x)$ intersect?

Comment: $F1 = |F(x)*F''(x)|$
and
$F2 = F'(x)^2$

Comment: Ah. OK. So we have:

$F(x)$, $F_1(x)=|F(x)F''(x)|$, and $F_2(x)=F'(x)^2$? I am asking just to make sure I fully understand.

Comment: Yes! and i want to know where F1 intersects F2.  In fact, i want to know where (over 3, 8) is F1 < F2

Comment: Does this help? I have to leave and cannot continue the problem:

\begin{align}
F(x)&=-\frac{x^3-14x^2+7x+203}{(x-8)(x-3)}\\
F'(x)&=-\frac{(x^2-11x+49)^2}{(x-8)^2(x-3)^2}\\
F''(x)&=\frac{50(2x^3-33x^2+219x-539)}{(x-8)^3(x-3)^3}\\
|F(x)F''(x)|&=\frac{50 (2 x-11) (x^2-11x+49) (x^3-14x^2+7x+203)}{(x-8)^4(x-3)^4}\\
F'(x)^2&=\frac{(x^2-11x+49)^4}{(x-8)^4(x-3)^4}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Maple 16 ...

[image: computation]

Note $F1 > -10$ and $F2 > 50$, so there is no need to consider the absolute value of $F1$ for intersections.

Answer (score 0):

The first derivative is $3 x^2-28 x+ \frac {203}{5 (x-8)^2}-\frac {203}{5 (x-3)^2}+7$ and the second is $\frac {14}5 \left(\frac{29}{(x-3)^3}-\frac{29}{(x-8)^3}-10\right )+6 x$ (both from Alpha).  Unfortunately, the entry box isn't large enough for your whole problem, but a lot of the denominators will cancel.